# Can I pass the string in PHP extension by reference with separating from other variables?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I have example code:

```
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO(arginfo_refstring, 0)
    ZEND_ARG_INFO(1, s1)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

const zend_function_entry refstring_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(refstring, arginfo_refstring)
    PHP_FE_END
};

PHP_FUNCTION(refstring)
{
    char *s1;
    int s1_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &s1, &s1_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    s1[0] = 'X';
}
```

And php code:

```
$s1 = 'hello';
$s2 = $s1;
refstring($s1);
var_dump($s1, $s2);
```

I expect:

```
string(5) "Xello"
string(5) "hello"
```

But i got:

```
string(5) "Xello"
string(5) "Xello"
```

> How can I separate `$s2` from `$s1`, but keep the ability to change `$s1` inside function?

I known about SEPARATE_ZVAL and co., but they did not help...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of a mechanism called *copy on write*.

After this lines:

```
$s1 = 'hello';
$s2 = $s1;
```

`$s1` and `$s2` are both independent variables (zvals), but they point to the same(!) data in memory - because both share the same value, meaning none of them has been changed so far.

If you would:

```
$s1 = 'foo';
```

... PHP would internally update the zval behind `$s1` in a way that it's value points to a different portion of memory.

However, since you are modifying the value in an extension function, this function would need to take care on that itself:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(refstring)
{
    zval *s1;
    char *string;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &s1)
        != SUCCESS
    ) {
        return;
    }   

    // copy the value before writing to it
    string = strdup(s1->value.str.val);
    string[0] = 'X';

    ZVAL_STRING(s1, string, 1);
}
```

Note that I'm using a `zval *` rather than using a pure string for the input parameter.

Further note that, the above function works as expected. However, I'm not sure if there is a MACRO for that purpose which can be used more elegantly.

Comment: Yes, I known about CoW. I need in-place update the $s1, rather than returning new string.

Comment: The length of the string can be very large (tens of megabytes), but I change several bytes in it.

Comment: You told that you know about CoW: Even if you change(write) just a single byte, you need to copy it the whole string. That's the deal. I don't know details about your current problem, but as long as you stored strings of multiple MB into a string variable, you need to copy the whole variable.

Comment: ... but since that would obviously introduces huge memory requirements, you may need to find a different way of designing your extensions. Probably its a good a idea to create a resource type (stream?) for that portions of data. Take the mysql extension for example, it does not return an array containing all data from a database query, it returns a mysql result resource where you can iterate over without having all the data in memory.

Comment: Just a small update:

string = strdup(s1->value.str.val);

Change to string = strdup(s1->value.str->val);

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce this atm. Are you using `z` or `s` for the type?